# Can we use GPT-2 to smooth out / correct text?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing, gpt

Are we able to use models like GPT-2 to smooth out/correct text? For instance if I have two paragraphs that need some text to make the transition easier to read, could this text be generated? And, could it find inconsistencies between the paragraphs and fix them?

As an example, imagine we're reordering some text so that we can apply the [pyramid principle](https://medium.com/lessons-from-mckinsey/the-pyramid-principle-f0885dd3c5c7). What I'd like to do is reorder the sentences/paragraphs and still have a coherant story. The following three sentences for instance, start with a statement and then have some facts to support it. What's missing is the story that joins them together, right now they're three independent sentences.

> The strawberry is the best fruit based on its flavor profile, its coloring and texture and the nutritional profile.
>
> Strawberries are very rich in antioxidants and plant compounds, which may have benefits for heart health and blood sugar control.
>
> Strawberries have a long history and have been enjoyed since the Roman times.

Feel free to point me at things to read, I have not been able to find anything like this in my searches.

Comment: Could you give an example of "two paragraphs that need some text to make the transition easier to read" and how you would make that correction without AI as an editor? It would make it clearer what task you were hoping to automate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added an example.

Comment: Your example is nice, thank you, but seems to be an entirely different task to "smooth out/correct text". Please could you focus the question on just one well-specifiied task? Also, to be super clear, can you please show an imagined output from the task. Simply sorting the paragraphs by length probably solves your pyramid principle task with 90% accuracy in any case . . .